# For loop indentation is not taking place in jinja2 templating in vscode

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code, jinja2

I am writing a for loop or if else using jinja2 templating but it is not giving me indentation in vscode. Fore example, I wrote this:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<h2>This is Item List</h2>

{% for item in items %}
    <p>{{items}}</p>
{% endfor %}

{% endblock content %}
```

But when I press `Ctrl` `s` or save it manually, it loses the indentation. The code becomes like this:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<h2>This is Item List</h2>

{% for item in items %}
<p>{{items}}</p>
{% endfor %}

{% endblock content %}
```

This is happening for for loops, if else and everything inside jinja2 templating. Not happening in normal python codes.
This is not giving any error, but I feel distressed. How to solve it.

Answer (score 4):

You need to download this extension to format the .j2 file https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=monosans.djlint